# function returns a whole array instead of value

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I am writing a function that takes an array of names and returns the name that are less than 10 characters. But, my code below returns me the whole array and I think that is because the length of the array is less than 10.

What can I do for it to check the elements rather than the whole array

```
const usernames = ["mark", "staceysmom197800000"];
function validUserNames(usernames) {
  return usernames.filter((m) => usernames.length < 10).map((m) => usernames);
}
```

My desired output is "mark".

Comment: What's the purpose of the filter if it doesn't filter on each item? Or the map that returns the original list for each item? Have you checked out the docs for either function?

Comment: I think I framed the question wrong. I need the new filter to only consists of name that are less than 10 characters which I achieved by specifying an index. However, it is iterating and giving me 2 outputs. "mark" and "mark" which is not my desired output. I could not understand what is happening, hence the question.

Comment: `usernames.filter(m => m.length < 10)`

Comment: @NicholasTower Thank you , this really helped and also solved my confusion as I can see where I went wrong. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really they both have it but use m instead of usernames. "m" is the function local variable and usernames is the one for outside the function.

```js
const usernames = ["mark", "staceysmom197800000"];
function validUserNames(usernames) {
  return usernames.filter((m) => m.length < 10);
}

console.log(validUserNames(usernames));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't map over the array after filtering:

```js
const usernames = ["mark", "staceysmom197800000"];
function validUserNames(usernames) {
  return usernames.filter((m) => m.length < 10);
}

console.log(validUserNames(usernames));
```

Comment: This brings me back to my old problem where both the names are being returned without being filtered. My filtering is for the names that are less than 10 characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot add a screenshot here. 

but, this was my output. 


(2) ["mark", "staceysmom197800000"]

However, when I replace the usernames.length with m.length it works fine.

Comment: Turns out you were using `usernames.length` (as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788553/15781079)). The filter function will always return true since `usernames.length` is 2. You need to use `m` instead.

Comment: @MrMythical Didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change the return to `return usernames.filter((m) => usernames.length < 10).map((m) => usernames)[0];` to get back the first element from the filtered array

Comment: It solves my problem of not being able to filter but is giving me 2 outputs. 

validUserNames(usernames)
(2) ["mark", "mark"]0: "mark"1: "mark"length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

I think it is iterating over the array and printing it out both the times. How do I solve this ?

Comment: ah. I see the issue. filter on `m.length < 10`